# Pretéritos fuertes desusados

Tags: verbos, pretérito, historia

¿Cuáles son los verbos que en el período medieval o áurico tenía formas fuertes (pretérito irregular al que corresponden las terminaciones *-e, -iste, -o, -imos, -isteis, -(i)eron* en la modernidad)?  Por ejemplo, en el español moderno, tenemos *andar* cuya forma pretérita indefinida de la primera persona singular es «anduve».

Sé que *conocer* y *medir* también pertenecían a este grupo exclusivo (yo *conduve* y *mise*) pero ahora tienen flexión regular, pero no sabía si hay más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro, justo después de preguntar, encontré [una respuesta](http://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?pid=S0718-93032009000100003&script=sci_arttext).  Modificando la información allí un poco, tenemos:

- **ceñir**: *cinx-*
- **creer**: *crov-* <sub>(sería *cruv-* ahora)</sub>
- **fuir**: *fux-*
- **prender**: *pris-*
- **responder**: *respus-*
- **ser**: *sov-* <sub>(sería *suv-* ahora)</sub>
- **reír**: *ris-*
- **vivir**: *visc-*
- **yacer**: *yog-* <sub>(sería *yug-* ahora)</sub>